# Error using plotly with Angular: error TS2707

Tags: angular, typescript, plotly

I try to add plotly to my Angular application. After installing as described in the docs I get the following error when trying to run the application:

```bash
error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

84     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<PlotlyComponent, "plotly-plot", never, { "data": "data"; "layout": "layout"; "config": "config"; "frames": "frames"; "style": "style"; "divId": "divId"; "revision": "revision"; "className": "className"; "debug": "debug"; "useResizeHandler": "useResizeHandler"; "updateOnLayoutChange": "updateOnLayoutChange"; "updateOnDataChange": "updateOnDataChange"; "updateOnlyWithRevision": "updateOnlyWithRevision"; }, { "initialized": "initialized"; "update": "update"; "purge": "purge"; "error": "error"; "afterExport": "afterExport"; "afterPlot": "afterPlot"; "animated": "animated"; "animatingFrame": "animatingFrame"; "animationInterrupted": "animationInterrupted"; "autoSize": "autoSize"; "beforeExport": "beforeExport"; "buttonClicked": "buttonClicked"; "click": "click"; "plotlyClick": "plotlyClick"; "clickAnnotation": "clickAnnotation"; "deselect": "deselect"; "doubleClick": "doubleClick"; "framework": "framework"; "hover": "hover"; "legendClick": "legendClick"; "legendDoubleClick": "legendDoubleClick"; "react": "react"; "relayout": "relayout"; "restyle": "restyle"; "redraw": "redraw"; "selected": "selected"; "selecting": "selecting"; "sliderChange": "sliderChange"; "sliderEnd": "sliderEnd"; "sliderStart": "sliderStart"; "transitioning": "transitioning"; "transitionInterrupted": "transitionInterrupted"; "unhover": "unhover"; "relayouting": "relayouting"; "treemapclick": "treemapclick"; "sunburstclick": "sunburstclick"; }, never, ["*"], false, never>;
```

It seems to be an issue with my angular setup right? Here are my specs:

```bash
﻿﻿Angular CLI: 15.2.8
Node: 16.19.0
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.19
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 14.3.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.11
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.8
@angular/cdk                    14.2.7
@angular/cli                    15.2.8
@angular/flex-layout            14.0.0-beta.40
@angular/material               14.2.7
@schematics/angular             15.2.8
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

these types of errors occur because of version mismatches. check the library and angular versions. Can't give you a definite answer without more info. please attach the package.json file as well.

Comment: Yes it was.. I thought the latest version would work for my setup, but I gone with an older version (2.3.1) and that worked fine.

Comment: @KastenBrot can you share the steps to install older version. It's not working for me

Comment: @sarathchandra I just checked the npm page and tried a major version below the latest. So what I took was 4.0.4, I think I slipped in the line of my package.json on the answer above, sorry.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-plotly.js?activeTab=versions

EDIT: spelling